# Managing large volume tabular data

Tags: org-mode, org-table

I have an index of digital media (books, movies, etc.) containing name, author, year, pages, etc. which I maintain in an Org file as a table.

I preferred Org mode because I had a lot of stuff in my Org file, anyway -- around 200K 3,400 odd lines including the index. Moreover, cross-referencing, etc. could be quick and esay with everything in Org mode. Add to that the benefit of one-file-everything convenience.

Presently, there are around 400 rows and 10 columns in the index. I expect it to grow to a couple of thousand rows at most. No of columns will remain just the same. Most of the time, the data just enters in the index or gets modified. Occassionally, there is sorting and searching. Searching can be on the name, author, etc. But I have never noticed in lag in either of the operations. In any case, writes to searches are 10:1 or so.

But after a certain number of rows, around 300-350, operating the table becomes very slow. There is a significant lag between I entering the text or moving the cursor and it actually getting displayed on screen.

Is there a better way to manage such large volume tabular data?

Comment: Maybe try a database? Sqlite is very lightweight, but thousands of rows still don't mean any problem to it.

Comment: @choroba Could you please elaborate? Do I need to install some package? A newbie here, BTW.

Comment: What about https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Text-Based-Tables.html `table-mode`? It may be capable of more records. However, at some point, examining data line by line becomes prohibitively slow, so, you'd have to resort to some tools that operate on your data in a batch mode.

Comment: How much data are you anticipating? What do you want to do with the data? Do you do searches? What kinds of searches? What's the ratio of searches to writes? Once you can answer these questions, what implementation you choose to store the data will become clearer. Another question: why did you choose org-mode tables in the first place? BTW, even if you abandon tables, you might want to profile the code when you see slowness and send the results to the org-mode mailing list (you might also post your question there).

Comment: Another possible implementation within org-mode is by using properties. There is an [example](http://orgmode.org/org.html#Properties-and-columns) in the manual.

Comment: @Nick Thanks. Instead of answering your questions here in the comments, I will edit the question to provide the information. It will, then, be easier for others.

Comment: That's the best way indeed.